# Random Walk - Parallel processing

Tags: python, parallel-processing, montecarlo

I'm currently implementing a monte-carlo method to solve a diffusion equation. The solution can be expressed as a mathematical expectation of phi(W) where phi is a function (varies accordingly to the diffusion equation) and W is a symmetric random walk stopped at the boundary of the domain. To evaluate the function at a point x, I need to start every walk in the expectation from x.

I want to evaluate the function at a large number of points. So this is what I do:

1. I start simultaneously one walk from every point
2. I use the same steps for every point
3. Once each walk has reached the boundary, I stop
4. I repeat these operations N times, in order to approximate the mathematical expectation by the frequency over N simulations.

My code (Python) looks like this :

```
for k in range(N): #For each "walk"
    step = 0
    while not(every walk has reach the boundary):
        map(update_walk,points) #update the walk starting from each x in points
        incr(step)
```

The problem is : it is extremely long since N can be large and the number of points also. I am looking for ANY solution that will help me optimize this code.

I have thought of parallel processing (each walk is independent) with IPython but I did not succeed because it is inside a function (it returned an error like

> "could not launch function 'f' because it was not found as 'file.f' " but 'f' is define within file.big_f)

Comment: Can you give the update_walk code?  It would help to see the work you are doing at each step.  Is the walk as simple as +/- random.uniform(-delta,delta)? Until each one passes a bound?  Is there an upper bound on walk steps as in @mike-mckern 's code?  Also, do you want to continue updating every point or stop updating as each point reaches the bound?

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the few cases I might not use parallel computing.  I think it'd be faster to just use `numpy`.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> def walk(x, n=100, box=.5, delta=.2):
...   np.random.seed()
...   w = np.cumsum(x + np.random.uniform(-delta,delta,n))
...   w = np.where(abs(w) > box)[0]
...   return w[0] if len(w) else n
... 
>>> pwalk = np.vectorize(walk)
>>> pwalk(np.zeros(10))
array([10,  25, 4,   5, 100,  6,  28,   6,  25,  23])
```

I think you should know how to get the expectation value from there.

You could also have passed a tuple to the last argument of `np.random.uniform`, and then not needed to use `np.vectorize`.

Of course, if you wanted to use parallel computing, then you could pick a good `map` function, and call `walk` from the `map` instead of using `vectorize` as I did above.

```
>>> from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool as Pool
>>> p = Pool(4)
>>> p.map(walk, [0]*10)
[8, 7, 39, 7, 36, 7, 22, 27, 18, 31]
```

Using `pathos`, so the map can be called easily from the interpreter.
https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos

Answer (score 0):

Launching a computation in a separate process (which is what you want in order to avoid the GIL) will probably make use of the multiprocessing module. Launching X parallel processes can be done with the following code :

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from Queue import Queue
queue = Queue(maxsize=MAX_NODES) # this is the number of processes you will spawn
procs = [Process(target=f, args=(node, queue) for node in nodes] # node will be the node for each process , the queue is common to all of the processes
[p.start() for p in procs] # start them
results = []
for i in range(len(nodes):
    results.append(queue.get())
```

All you need to do is to modify the func (target function) to take the relevant number of args plus the queue, and at the end of the computation to call queue.put(result)

Hope this makes sense

Comment: I have tried to use a queue as you suggest but it never stops ! I do know why. Do you think it is because my function returns a ny.darray ? I do not know why. I have tried with pools also and it does not stop either (I update your post with my code). I do not know what to do...